# Spanning set theorem confusion

Tags: vector-spaces

**Theorem:** Let V be a vector space over K which has a finite spanning set,
and suppose that the vectors $v_1, . . . , v_r$ are linearly independent in V . Then we can
extend the sequence to a basis $v_1, . . . , v_n$ of V , where $n ≥ r$.

I dont know what this means, how can a span that is linearly independant be extended to make a basis? Wouldnt that mean adding in some linearly dependant vectors?

Comment: The linearly independent set may not span the whole space.  $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb R^3$, for instance.

Comment: Linearly independent intuitively means none of the vectors are redundant. Any set containing a single nonzero vector is linearly independent, but of course such a thing doesn't span $V$ if $V$ is bigger than 1-dimensional. On the other hand, this theorem says that that one vector can always be a part of a basis; you can't pick a "weird" vector that is somehow prohibited from being in a basis of $V$.